# Parent-Child Validation using SQL

Tags: sql, parent-child

How do I validate that child tables in a parent/child relationship in a relational database actually have legitimate parent keys?

I do not want to do this via the data dictionary--many real-world databases don't put in FK constraints.  I want to do it via the data itself.

I do not want this specific to a vendor product.  What is the generic SQL for this?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? And what does the table structure look like? And you need this via a SQL query or TSQL / PL/SQL?

Comment: I need it via SQL query...the table structure is i am having a root node with id=NULL which is the parent ...and there are multiple cases like these...so i need a query which can validate all samples in my table.

Comment: can you make an example into your post as to how the tables themselves look (thus if there is anything else that need to be taken into account) and what a typical data case of the data that needs validation looks like (thus to see if only that column null is invalid, or something else too,....)

Comment: Please update your question with the table structure and sample data. And also mention the DBMS

Answer (score 0):

You can count the orphans this way:

```
select count(*) from T_CHILD where FOO not in (select FOO from T_PARENT);
```

You can get their values this way:

```
select * from T_CHILD where FOO not in (select FOO from T_PARENT);
```

If you just want the nulls rather than the populated-but-invalid ones, do this:

```
select * from T_CHILD where FOO not in (select FOO from T_PARENT) and FOO is null;
```

You can do all of the above with a compound key.  Taking the first one above it would be:

```
select count(*) from T_CHILD where FOO, BAR not in (select FOO, BAR from T_PARENT);
```

If you have something like a Hive version that can't do compound, or if you just have a preference, you can do this:

```
select count(*) from T_CHILD where FOO||BAR not in (select FOO||BAR from T_PARENT);
```

You can also test via "exists" and "join" rather than "not in", and those other methods often are faster, but I find "not in" most intuitive and maintainable by lower-cost staff when a system moves to production.